# No data load my outputText of Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a question I have a DataTable, where I have a button in a column edit, capture the Id of the record, and make a list that record to load the data in the object system, peroHola, I have a question I have a DataTable, where I have a button in a column edit, capture the Id of the record, and make a list that record to load the data in the object system, but my text box value is charging.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="sis" value="#{listSistMB.system}"  
             paginator="true" rows="10" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" selection="#{listSistMB.system}"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Status" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{sis.stStatus}" onLabel="A" offLabel="I" />  
    </p:column> 

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Edit" />  
        </f:facet>                                              
        <p:commandButton id="selectEdit" action="#{listSistMB.editSystem}"
            icon="ui-icon-search" title="Editar System">
            <f:param name="codCode" value="#{sis.cdCode}"/>   
        </p:commandButton>                       
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In the controller I headed this way the system object.

```
@Component("listSistMB")
@Scope("view")
public class MantenanceSystemController implements Serializable{

    private System system = new System();

    public String editSystem(){     
        try {
            String cdCode = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
                                getRequestParameterMap().get("codCode");
            system = confSistemaService.buscarPorId(Long.valueOf(cdCode));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "register-system";
    }
```

It's not charging me the value of the text box.

```
<p:inputText value="#{listSistMB.system.nbNomCorto}" />
```

Comment: Are the p:dataTable and p:inputText enclosed in the same form?

Comment: I have not in another .xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *MantenanceSystemController* bean is in *@Scope("view")*

If the p:dataTable and p:inputText are not on the same view, the information will be lost when changing views.

Consider a different scope (e.g., Conversation) for the bean.